# Asp.NET Core 2 Authentication. SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync() succeeds, but User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I was following some tutorials on IdentityUser, and I think I did exactly as in tutorials, but when I try to login, I get "MyIdentity: False" (with LogInformation) even thou _signInManager succeeds, which seems to be very weird. I tried to set the users as confirmed, but with no result.

I'm working on Visual Studio on Mac.

Here's how I register my users:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            UserName = model.Email,
            Email = model.Email
        };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);
            return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
        }   
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

And here's how I try to login:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(
            model.Email,
            model.Password,
            model.RememberMe,
            lockoutOnFailure: false
        );

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("MyIdentity: " + User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);
            return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Login attempt.");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Here's how I configure the services for it:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<CmagruDBContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlite("Data Source=Cmagru.db",
        b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Presentation")));

services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<CmagruDBContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 3;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
});

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

And I do have `app.UseAuthentication();` in Configure

Comment: `PasswordSignInAsync` issues a Cookie that contains the login information, which isn't read until another request is made and the Cookie sent along with it.

Comment: @KirkLarkin then how do I check if the user is logged in? It's my first project...

Comment: Given that `result.Succeeded` is `true`, you know that the user is signed in. Try adding `[Authorize]` to an endpoint and then check the value of `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` there, after signing in.

Answer (score 3):

For other people who may encounter this problem:
In my case, I had to simply put `app.UseAuthentication();` before `app.UseMvc()` in `Configure()`. Otherwise, it doesn't work for me.

I think I missed that in documentation.

Comment: My `app.UseAuthentication();` isn't before everything else in `Configure()`: I have `app.UseStaticFiles()` and `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute()` before `UseAuthentication()`, and mine is still working fine....

Comment: @DavidLiang Yes, I'm sorry, I was too excited that it finally worked. It has to be before `UseMvc()` in my case. I'll edit

Comment: Thank you, Emil! I spent 2 hours, you saved my next hours!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I configured global `Authorize` with incorrect schema (JWT):

```cs
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();

    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    // ... other configurations
});
```

Therefore, all subsequent requests with proper Cookies were not authorized.

Just get rid of schema or specify correct one manually. Hope, it could save time for those, who encounter it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using .net5 and vs2022. For me, the 4 steps bellow in startup.cs must be exactly in the order of:

```
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => ...
```

I mis-placed the middle 2 in wrong order and it failed as what the question said.