# SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync() succeeds, but User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, razor-pages

I'm new to ASP.Net Core and trying to create an user authentication system. I'm using ASP.Net Core Identity user management. I have the below code for logging in an user.

**/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Login.cshtml.cs**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
            _logger.LogInformation(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.ToString());

            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
            return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return Page();
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Page();
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    });

    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    // Use a unique identity cookie name rather than sharing the cookie across applications in the domain.
    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = Configuration["CookieName"];
    });

    // Add SAML SSO services.
    services.AddSaml(Configuration.GetSection("SAML"));

    services.AddTransient<IPasswordHasher<IdentityUser>, CustomPasswordHasher>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            "default",
            "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

I need to set some attributes in the cookies when the user logs in, but I always get `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` `false` even if it shows `User logged in` in the logger and `PasswordSignInAsync` succeeds. How to log in the user inside `OnPostAsync` ?

N.B: User is logged in when redirected to home page after `PasswordSignInAsync` succeeds.

I've already checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49799370/asp-net-core-2-authentication-signinmanager-passwordsigninasync-succeeds-but) but it didn't solve my issue.

Comment: For me a similar situation arose when the auth middleware wasn’t set up correctly. Could you show also your configuration in Startup? It may be that this part is ok but the part reading auth info isn’t getting it from the correct place.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I've added my **Startup.cs** code. Can you please have a look?

Comment: I had same problem and I realized that I misspelled defaultScheme for Authentication service.  Looking your code I cannot see a line for for AddAuthentication with AddCookie 
 services.AddAuthentication("Identity.Application").AddCookie();

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`, it only works for sub-request after `PasswordSignInAsync`.

You could try options below:

1. Redirect to another action to set the cookies.

   ```
   public class LoginModel : PageModel
   {
       private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser<int>> _signInManager;
       private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

       public LoginModel(SignInManager<IdentityUser<int>> signInManager, ILogger<LoginModel> logger)
       {
           _signInManager = signInManager;
           _logger = logger;
       }

       //rest code

       public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
       {
           returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

           if (ModelState.IsValid)
           {
               // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
               // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
               var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
               if (result.Succeeded)
               {
                   _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                   return LocalRedirect($"~/Identity/Account/Login?handler=SetIdentity&returnUrl={returnUrl}");
               }
               if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
               {
                   return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
               }
               if (result.IsLockedOut)
               {
                   _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                   return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
               }
               else
               {
                   ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                   return Page();
               }
           }

           // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
           return Page();
       }

       public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetSetIdentityAsync(string returnUrl)
       {
           _logger.LogInformation(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.ToString());

           return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use `_signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync`

   ```
   public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
   {
       returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
           // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
           var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
           if (result.Succeeded)
           {
               var user = await _signInManager.UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
               var userPrincipal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);
               var identity = userPrincipal.Identity;
               return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
           }
           if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
           {
               return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
           }
           if (result.IsLockedOut)
           {
               _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
               return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
           }
           else
           {
               ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
               return Page();
           }
       }

       // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
       return Page();
   }
   ```

Comment: I use this and CreateUserPrincipalAsync, but `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is false

Answer (score 1):

Just answering for the **Future Searchers**.
I **had** this Problem before.

My Problem was That The Cookie for the Identity after Login Was There in the Browser but the Application Couldn't Read it, I just Added Both **app.UseAuthorization();** and **app.UseAuthentication();** to my program.cs
then I read the Cookies just fine.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string username,string password)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return Redirect("/");
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
        {
            var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(username, password, true,false);
            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Wrong", "Username or Password are wrong");
            }
            else {
                return Redirect("/");
            }
        }
        else {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Cant Be Empty", "username and password can not be empty.");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the first posts I found trying to research my issue when adding support for external logins.

Signing in with individual accounts was working without issue but adding external login (`AddMicrosoftAccount`) presented with the same symptoms as this post. Changing `SameSiteMode.Strict` to `SameSiteMode.Lax` (the default) allowed the first request after authentication to register as authenticated.

```
.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // First request after authentication shows IsAuthenticated = false
    // options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;

    // First request after authentication IsAuthenticated = true
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
...
```