# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false although SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync() succeeds

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I did find similar questions but none of the provided answers helped me.

I did follow a tutorial to add Identity to my ASP.net Core 2.2 project (https://retifrav.github.io/blog/2018/03/20/csharp-dotnet-core-identity-mysql/)

Even though SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync() succeeds, both User.Identity.IsAuthenticated and SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User) are false in the _Layout view.

_Layout.cshtml:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<MySiteUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<MysiteUser> UserManager

......................

<div>
            @if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
            {
                <div>Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</div>
            }

            @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                <div>User is authenticated </div>
            }


 </div>
```

In Startup.CS, in ConfigureServices I have:

```
services.AddIdentity<MySiteUSer, MySiteRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();


            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;

                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;

                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            });

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login");            

            services.AddMvc();
```

In Startup.CS, in Configure() I have:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider services)
        {
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseAuthentication(); ;

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

        }
```

In AccountController I have:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");                   

                    var user = await _signInManager.UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);
                    var userPrincipal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);
                    var identity = userPrincipal.Identity;
                    if(identity.IsAuthenticated)                       
                      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }

                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form 
            return View(model);
        }
```

MySiteUser and MySiteRole just override default Identity classes

```
public class MySiteUser : IdentityUser<int>
    {
    }

 public class MySiteRole : IdentityRole<int>
    {
    }
```

Edit:

Because all replies are about the Controller, before this one I used the following code in AccountController

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {                                         
                      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }

                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form 
            return View(model);
        }
```

The result was the same.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Why are you creating `userPrincipal` like that? This is unusual...

Comment: @Kirk Larkin I followed second option from the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54547742/signinmanager-passwordsigninasync-succeeds-but-user-identity-isauthenticated I am trying to show some options in the view based on the fact that a user is signed in or not

Comment: @ Kirk Larkin I just want to have the user signed in and use that information in views and other controllers. Right now, it redirects to home page, which means _Lauot is loaded and SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User) should be true and I can use that info to show some links just for signed in users.

Comment: I don't understand why your login code needs to check `IsAuthenticated` before `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");`. If `result.Succeeded` is `true` then you can just call that redirect anyway, right?

Comment: @ Kirk Larkin I've already told you, I just followed the suggestion in the link above. However, thats not the problem before adding that code the result was the same. Before that I had if (result.Succeeded)
   {                    
       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
   }
in Controller and the result was the same.

Comment: Alright, fine. I can't help with this then, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I've just find a solution, although I don't understand why it works. I've checked Chrome Developer Tools to see if the authentication cookie is set, and it wasn't. 
After I deleted all cookies for the site, the app set the cookie and all works well.

I also tested the simpler `AccountController` and that works fine, too:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var result = await _signInManager
              .PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password,
                Model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {                                         
                  return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form 
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check `if(identity.IsAuthenticated)` before redirecting user to home page. If the code reaches the `(result.Succeeded)` block, it means user is authenticated. `if(identity.IsAuthenticated)` will be true only at the end of the request, meaning you have returned an `HttpResponse` (or something) that will create a cookie on client side.

So the solution is to remove the condition inside the `Login` action.

```
                /*if(identity.IsAuthenticated) <===== remove this */
                  return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

**EDITS**: Don't forget that when you use `RedirectToAction`, it's still a same request so the cookie will not be created yet. Instead, create and use a temporary success view as I usually do.

```
  /*if(identity.IsAuthenticated)  <===== remove this */
   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); <===== remove this */
   /*put url in viewbag or use returnUrl variable*/
  @ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("index","home"/*,null,Request.Url.Scheme*/);
  return View("LoginSuccess");
```

and here is what to put in your **LoginSuccess.cshtml** view

```
  <h2>Authenticated. Wait 2 seconds or click continue</h2>
  <p><a href="@ViewBag.ReturnUrl">
     Continue</a></p>

   <script>
     setTimeout(function () {
         window.location = "@ViewBag.ReturnUrl";
        }, 2000)
   </script>
```

PS: You may need to use partial view to avoid conflict with your layout page headers... `return PartialView("LoginSuccess");`

Comment: I removed that, with the same result. User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is still false in the View. As I replied to Kirk Larkin's comment above, before that I used just if(result.Succeeded) { return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); } in Controller and the result was the same.

Comment: Because when you use RedirectToAction, it's still a same request so the cookie will not be created yet. Instead, create and use a temporary success view as I usually do. See my updated answer dude

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have stumbled on this answer to this. First try this in IE, it may work there. Apparently Chrome is quite fussy regarding the cookie that is used for the Authentication unless you are talking to it in HTTPS. If you are in development and using HTTP and using Chrome the IsSignedIn(User) *may* fail. This is unbelievably annoying and quite a productivity sink. HTH