# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated AND _signInManager.IsSignedIn(User) return always null / fasle IN MVC CORE 6 2022

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a new asp.net MVC core 6 application .try to authenticate users ( not by using Identity scaffolding ) .. however the the SignInmanger is always return False

**Login function**

[image]

**programe.cs**

[image]

Full code snippet for login :

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginVM loginvm)
    { // this wil return view model


        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(loginvm);
        }


        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(loginvm.Username);

        if (user != null)
        {
            // if we have user let us check the password

            var checkpsssword = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, loginvm.Password);

            if (checkpsssword)
            {
                var letUserLoginIn = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, loginvm.Password, false, false);

                if (letUserLoginIn.Succeeded)
                {
                    var tempo = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

                    var isok = _signInManager.IsSignedIn(User);
                    ViewBag.tempo=tempo;
                    ViewBag.isok = isok;

                  return  RedirectToAction("index", "Movie");
                }
                
                ModelState.AddModelError("Error","can login innnnn");
                TempData["Error"] = "Password is not correct! !";
                return View(loginvm);
            }
            else
            {
                // password wrong
                TempData["Error"] = "Password is not correct! !";
            }

        }

        TempData["Error"] = "no user found ya mozznoz!";
        return View(loginvm);//STRONGLY TYPED VIEW 


    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync() succeeds, but User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54547742/signinmanager-passwordsigninasync-succeeds-but-user-identity-isauthenticated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One part @Kevin have mentioned above, and another part was the missing of authentication mechanism register.

It should be something like `builder.Services.AddAuthentication(opts => opts.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie();`

`AddAuthentication` part add all the necessary middlewares and config to setup authentication process. Here, we specify `DefaultScheme` as `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`

`AddCookie` tell asp.net Core that we want to store the login information in cookie, therefore, a response that tell client to save a cookie with pre-defined information was sent(and the name for that authentication mechanism of choice was default to `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`).

For every subsequent requests, the cookie was included then server know, we already logged in

Comment: Thank you for this @Gordon , I just change the following lines and all starts to work fine ! ... yet. I cant understand why this issue happen( or where in docmentation we can find the required steps )

Comment: The changes in the following image :

https://ibb.co/9NG283g

Comment: There are a few more types on authentication process, like `authentication`, `signin`, `signout`, `challenge`,... I saw on image that we just specify the `DefaultAuthenticateScheme`, so what are `DefaultSignInScheme`, `DefaultSignOutScheme`, and other missing part ? `DefaultScheme` was set as fallback for all of them. For more information about what they responsible for, I consider [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#authenticate) as a good starting point.

Comment: In the doc it refer to Jwt mechanism, but it seems official document on cookie mechanism is a bit hard to find... So, just take what they do in the process pipeline, not the exact implementation

Comment: Thanks for that ... do you have full example for `reset-password` , ' verifiy-email' ? I have some issues with using cookies auth for my app...

Comment: sound a lot like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)